# Joining two results of sql

Tags: sql, h2

I have two queries and both works on two tables with similar columns,
**Query 1** produces the following results, since the result has 46 rows – a part of it is shown here.

[image]

**Query 2** produces the following results,

[image]

Now I want to combine then as follows, result should have more than 46 rows (depending on how many similarities they have based on WC). Both result has the SS (Session for SS) column.

[image]

This is what I’ve tried,

```
select ss, wc, wc_efficiency1, wc_efficiency2 from
(
    Query 1
) t1

join

(
    Query 2
) t2
ON t1.ss = t2.ss
```

But query doesn’t execute, showing errors and even if I make some changes to overcome the errors, it runs for infinite time, no output.

Comment: Does this h2 engine support a UNION operator?

Comment: yes it supports,

Comment: `ss` is **not** unique. Your `JOIN` produces a partial Cartesian product.

Comment: how can I achieve the desired result, what sql command I need, Please @PM 77-1

Comment: I do not understand how you came up with the expected result.  Did you by any chance intend to JOIN on `ss` **and** `wc`?

Comment: I didn't get the result yet, I am trying to get it. @PM77-1

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can approach this and it depends on whether the results from query 1 and query 2 are unique, need to appear as a single row, or need to have their efficiencies aggregated/calculated somehow.

If the results are unique (there will not be an SS + WC combination that is the same) then you can do the following:

```
SELECT ss, wc, wc_efficiency
FROM query1
UNION ALL
SELECT ss, wc, wc_efficiency
FROM query2
```

If the results are *not* unique, meaning you may have an SS + WC combination that is in both queries then you could do the following:

```
SELECT 
    q1.ss, 
    q1.wc, 
    q1.wc_efficiency AS [wc_efficiency1],
    q2.wc_efficiency AS [wc_efficiency2]
FROM QUERY1 q1, QUERY2 q2
WHERE q1.ss = q2.ss 
AND q1.wc = q2.wc
```

*OR*

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN q1.ss IS NOT NULL THEN q1.ss
        WHEN q2.ss IS NOT NULL THEN q2.ss
    END AS [ss],
    CASE 
        WHEN q1.wc IS NOT NULL THEN q1.wc
        WHEN q2.wc IS NOT NULL THEN q2.wc
    END AS [wc],
    q1.wc_efficiency AS [wc_efficiency1],
    q2.wc_efficiency AS [wc_efficiency2]
FROM QUERY1 q1
    FULL OUTER JOIN QUERY2 q2
    ON q1.ss = q2.ss AND q1.wc = q2.wc
```

I prefer the latter option, but they should both work similarly and you can use ISNULL to set a wc_efficiency of 0 if you don't want null values for reporting/graphing purposes...

edit: forgot that if there is something in the second query not in the first set of results you'd need to account for that, you may need a different join but can also use a case statement and I'll edit the third option above to reflect that.

Comment: I tried the second one and it produces some results, not exactly what I was looking for still thank you, it produces 138 rows, but I think it should not exceed (46+6) rows,. A UNION produces only three columns but I want 4 columns, SS, WC, efficiency1 and efficiency2

Comment: Try the third option.  The first one is only for a situation where there won't be an SS/WC combination that appears in both queries (so having two efficiency columns would be pointless).  If you're getting 138 rows with the second option then I suspect it has to do with how you've constructed your actual queries, but it's hard for me to say since I have no idea what they are.

Comment: SS and WC none of them are null,

Comment: I updated the question with a sample of query 1, if that helps to understand the problem better @Aithos

Comment: the third option is not supported by h2